# About the design of the database table

Tags: mysql, database

Described as follows：

In my project, the design table encountered confusion.

Now I have four different content types，Each field is not exactly the same.

Such as ,

> Table A, B, and C have a "type" field, and table D is not, and because of the "type" field, there are some fields that are different values.
>
> For example, in Table A, if "type = 0", the "length" field can be 0.00, otherwise the "length" field can not be 0.00. However, in table D, the length field must exist and have a "sheet" field more than tables A, B, and C.

In this case, I will designed  Table A, B, C, D into different tables, that is, A, B, C, D is distinguished by the table name. **Is it too bloated?**

And I need to associate another table (Table E) with data of Table A, B, C, and D. According to my previous practice, I need to add a field in the associated table, used to distinguish between different tables, so that it can find the correct table content. (Very inconvenient)

If I design tables A, B, C, D into the same table, and then through a field to distinguish A, B, C, D these four different content,This will cause some fields to be redundant.

> For example, table D must have a "sheet" field, and tables A, B, and C are not required. Design to the same table, each table A, B, C field will be more a "sheet" field。
>
> The benefits are also obvious, Table E can be directly associated with the same table "id" field.

**Designed into four tables, distinguished by table name**

**Or designed as one table, more of the distinction between the operation, completed in the code** ??

---

update..

My four tables (ABCD), only the table D has a "sheet" field, less with a "type" field, other fields are the same with Table A/B/C 's fields , designed into one  same table is no problem.

> however,I have an operation to paginate the data in the table, where the ABC type of data can be queried, but the D type of data needs a "group by " query (for example, the D type of data,  The "sum" is calculated for the "sheet" field with the same data  as the "width" field and the "length" field).

so if I designed into one same table,how can I achieve the above requirements。

thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Depend on your needs, but you can use a main table for the common fields, and child tables for the additional information.

Main table:

```
TableABCDE: { ABCDE_id (Pk), field1, fieldN}
```

Childs Table

```
DataA:  { A_ID (PK), ABCDE_ID (FK), field_A1, fieldAN}
DataB:  { B_ID (PK), ABCDE_ID (FK), field_B1, fieldBN}
DataC:  { C_ID (PK), ABCDE_ID (FK), field_C1, fieldCN}
DataD:  { D_ID (PK), ABCDE_ID (FK), field_D1, fieldDN}
DataE:  { E_ID (PK), ABCDE_ID (FK), field_E1, fieldEN}
```

Comment: First thanks for your answer. And I have updated the question.Table E just like an "order table",and Table A B C D just like the  different  ''commodity table".so , A/B/C/D has different fields , such as ,D has 'sheet' field,do not have 'type' field.Only this one is different. new question is just like the post of mine.(updated)，I hope you can guide me，thanks again.